# Circular dependency error during creating migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities that are related by a foreign key with a one-to-many relationship. when I try to perform a migration, I get an error related to the circular dependency. i tried to create an OnDelete.Cascade rule in DbContext but the error is still the same.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Image>()
            .HasOne<Part>(i =>i.Part)
            .WithMany(a =>a.Images)
            .HasForeignKey(i=>i.PartId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in
> the data to be saved: 'Project.Models.Part [Deleted] Image { 'ImageId'
> } <- Project.Models.Image [Deleted] Images { 'PartId' } <-
> Project.Models.Part [Deleted]

```
public class Part
{
    [Column("PartId")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }

}

public class Image
{
    [Column("ImageId")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool isPoster { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Part))]
    public Guid PartId { get; set; }
    public Part Part { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your `create` transaction? I guess the order of operations or the way these operations are done might be a reason

Comment: @E.Shcherbo I dont think thats the problem, because the error occurs when creating the migration.

Comment: oh sorry, misread the question. I thought the problem occurs during the **transaction** of creating objects.

Comment: Did you try without any `ForeignKey` (since you already have defined the ForeignKey in fluent API the attribute could be redundant) attribute or with a ForeignKey attribute like this `[ForeignKey("Part")]`